# Can you please help me with div id?

Tags: html, css

EDIT: First of all, sorry for not pasting the link directly. Secondly, thank you ALL for the help, everything works now. Thank you Manoz especially for pasting my code and fixing it. This website is magical, I've been trying (and failing) to make my code work all day yesterday, so I thought to give this website a try and got much more help than I expected. THANK YOU!!

I'm an amateur programmer in school, having a lot of trouble with div id. Here is a link of how my code looks like:

http://convert.neevia.com/docs/e7416408-ff15-4c01-954c-603bfd1ce941/test11.jpg

The problem I'm encountering here is that anything from #title to #footer is not showing up in the browser. In other words, it is not linking any id (such as #title) to the HTML code .

I would really, really appreciate some help. Thank you very much.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    div{
    border:solid 2px;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
    color:green;
    }

    #title
    {
    height:150px;
    }

    #menu
    {
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    height:450px;
    }

    #mainarea
    {
    margin-left:180px;
    margin-top:10px;
    }

    #content
    {
    }

    #footer
    {
    height:30px;
    text-align:right;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="title">
    <p>The title</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
    <p>the menu</p>
    </div>
    <div id="mainarea">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html
```

Changes are being appeared when I change anything from `#menu` to `#footer` in CSS.

Comment: Please post the code to the question as text, not as a picture. (Often people need/want to try the code to give an answer and no-one is going to type it in from a picture.)

Comment: First question... Did you clear your browser cache? I don't see any particular problem with your code.

Comment: In addition to what Juhana said: There is a typo in the html closing  tag. The `>` is missing.

Comment: Questions related to problems with your code require you to put *the minimal amount of code required to reproduce the problem* into the question, attempted solutions and what you expect to happen. Please edit your question to add this.

Comment: What about the `<body>` tag before the `<head>` tag? You have declared two body tags instead of one.

Answer (score 2):

If Tony Barnes's idea didn't work (which you should try), you might just not be saving the file before you refresh your browser.

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong with your code. Until you post it in your question (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) I'm not going to try it out, but it could be a caching problem. Ctrl+Shift+R (Win) Cmd+Shift+R (Mac) to refresh the page with a new cache. I noticed that you're using Dreamweaver. Don't. Especially do not use it's preview option. There are many better (free) text editors.

Caching probably isn't an issue though because it's all inline CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me, is just that there is a cache file that is present in the browser. I had the same issue, so I had to remove that using CTRL + F5.

Otherwise, what does the red line means in the code? Does your text editors shows the error when you hover over to it? I am sure it would help you.

Third thing would be, to check the Html Inspector from your browser. To check that press F12, I am sure you will get the styled properties there, this way you will get to know which properties are being applied.

If the updated ones are not present in the Browser, then the cache is the issue. If they are being overridden then you will also know how!